# Read Only Custom Properties

Tags: vba, ms-word

I managed to add custom properties (metadata) for MS Word from VBA, but how do I make it read only so that it cannot be changed easily?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Depending on what sort of scenario you're trying to avoid, you might be able to ["obfuscate"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) the properties by encrypting the contents somehow. That would make it harder for a user to figure out how to change them to something useful - but wouldn't stop the user from "breaking" it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using document properties use **document variables** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb212231.aspx). You can only access them through code. There's no UI for them.

Here's some old VB6/VBA functions I used for them:

```
Public Sub SetVariable(oDocument As Word.Document, sName As String, sValue As String)

      Dim oVariable As Word.Variable

      Set oVariable = LocateVariable(oDocument, sName)

      If Not oVariable Is Nothing Then

          oVariable.Value = sValue

      Else

          oDocument.Variables.Add sName, sValue

      End If

End Sub

Public Function GetVariable(oDocument As Word.Document, sName As String) As String

      Dim oVariable As Word.Variable

      Set oVariable = LocateVariable(oDocument, sName)

      If Not oVariable Is Nothing Then

          GetVariable = oVariable.Value

      Else

          GetVariable = ""

      End If

End Function

Public Function LocateVariable(oDocument As Word.Document, sName As String) As Word.Variable

      Dim oVariable As Word.Variable

      For Each oVariable In oDocument.Variables

          If StrComp(oVariable.Name, sName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

              Set LocateVariable = oVariable

              Exit Function

          End If

      Next

      Set LocateVariable = Nothing

End Function
```